# VSTO Outlook Addin VB.Net - Jagged array that counts instances of id in subject

Tags: arrays, vb.net, outlook, vsto

So i am relatively new to VB, and programming in general, I would love tips in all aspects of this, but i am creating a VSTO add-in for Outlook for use with an email inbox being modified by a handful of users. The issue i am having is with one of the buttons designed for reporting purposes.

To mark an email when it is picked up by a user, i have a button that modifies the subject line to append "Actioned - userid - date&time - " to the subject line. The user ID is always 7 characters. What i would like to do is iterate through all selected emails, grab the userid from that subject line, and create an array that shows the total number of emails that have been actioned by each user.

The output of the array should be in the format of userid count. Grabbing the userid is simple as it will always be in the same position of the subject line.

I have it working in a basic testing form by creating a string with all userid's and then iterating through it (ignore the Do While Count, it is just for testing) but I would like to change it to be much simpler within an array.

```
    For Each MItem In oSel
        If InStr(MItem.Subject, "Duplicate - ") Then
            dupeCount = dupeCount + 1
        End If
        If InStr(MItem.Subject, "Actioned - ") Then
            emailUser = Left(Mid(MItem.Subject, (InStr(MItem.Subject, "Actioned - ") + 11)), 7)
            userArray = userArray & " " & emailUser
            emailCount = emailCount + 1
        Else
            NoID = NoID + 1
        End If
    Next MItem
    Do While Count > 0
        If Len(userArray) > 2 Then
            arrayUser = Left(userArray, 8)
            userCount = (Len(userArray) - Len(Replace(userArray, arrayUser, ""))) / Len(arrayUser)
            markedCount = markedCount + userCount
            msgStr = msgStr & arrayUser & ": " & userCount & " | "
        End If
        If InStr(userArray, arrayUser) Then
            userArray = Replace(userArray, arrayUser, "")
        End If
        If userArray = vbNullString Then
            Count = 0
            GoTo CompileEmail
        End If
    Loop
```

How would i go about this, i would assume it would be something along the lines of:

```
 If InStr(MItem.Subject, "Actioned - ") Then
        emailUser = Left(Mid(MItem.Subject, (InStr(MItem.Subject, "Actioned - ") + 11)), 7)
        If userArray.Contains(emailUser) Then
                userLoc = Array.IndexOf(userArray, emailUser)
                '' Get jagged array details at userLoc
                '' Modify jagged array to iterate count for that userid by 1
                '' Place modified jagged array back in userArray
```

And i'm a little bit stumped at this point as to how to create/manipulate an array that would have this outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with Outlook so hopefully someone more experienced will answer this but I can give you one hint.

The `MItem` has a lot of properties that are not visible to user but are essential part of the object (`MailItem`) like `BillingInformation` field (*or any other field that is not displayed to user*)

So you can do something like this when you are updating the Subject line

```
mItem.BillingInformation = "JohnSmith"
mItem.Save
```

The above adds user **JohnSmith** to the field called `BillingInformation` and saves the mail item.
Later when you want to create your report of users, you will simple filter all mail items

```
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim fd As Outlook.Folder

ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
fd = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim mItems As Outlook.Items
mItems = fd.Items

Dim filtered As Outlook.Items
filtered = mItems.Restrict("[BillingInformation] = 'JohnSmith'")

Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem
For i as Integer = 1 To filtered.Count
    mItem = mItems(i)
    Debug.Print mItem.Subject
Next i
```

Comment: I have thought of doing it this way, the only thing is I am iterating through these messages by selection not by entire folder, and I need to output reports in the format of:
'<employee#> : <count>' repeated for every found employee number in the selection rather than searching per employee (although that is a handy search function i can add).

Comment: Well, I thought that when a user is taking an email, she will press a button that alter the Subject line and at that point you add the user id to the 'special' property.
Later when you (they) do the selection, you get the selected items and go through only the selected items to get the report. The main thing is that you can pretty easily (hopefully) go through the selection, get all the user id, store is some de-dup collection and show the report?